# storing value of the node instead of Id of the node in map in gremlin for mentioned gremlin query

Tags: java, gremlin

I have used given below query **g.V().as('out').out().as('in').select('out','in').groupCount().unfold().filter(select(values).is(gt(1))).select(keys)**

it is displaying out:v[1234],in:v[3456] .....

**but instead of displaying Ids of the node I want to display values of the node like out:ICIC1234,in:HDFC234**

I have modified query as **g.V().values("name").as('out').out().as('in').values("name").select('out','in'). groupCount().unfold().filter(select(values).is(gt(1))).select(keys)**

but it is showing the error like classcastException, each vertex to be traversed use indexes for fast iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can changed the first part of your traversal to use a `by('name')` after the first `select`:

```
g.V().as('out').
  out().as('in').
  select('out','in').
    by('name')
  groupCount().
  unfold().
  filter(select(values).is(gt(1))).
  select(keys)
```